# Deletion in bst tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search class and i want to write a function for deleting a special node but i don't know how. 
the basic class is :

```
class Node {
    friend class Tree;
private:
    long long rep;
    Node *left, *right;
    string data;
public:
    Node( string d )
        : data( d ), left( NULL ), right( NULL ), rep( 1 ) {}
};

class Tree {
private:
    Node *root;
public:
    void delete_node( Node *cur , string s );
    void delete_node_helper( string s );
};
```

Comment: The best way is to use smart pointer as `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*`.

Comment: How exactly do you want to delete a node? Do you want to replace it with a placeholder or actually delete? Should the tree rebalance after this deletion? What is the expected asymptotic complexity?

Comment: And what is `rep`?

Comment: for rep: i have a passage and i want to make a bst tree of this passage . i wrote insert and search member functions for this class and of course rep is the number of repetition of the word.

Comment: dear @alexeykuzmin0 , it is not necessary to have a balanced tree. i just want to delete a node so that the deleted node not print in the output after traverse the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Delete a special node from a BST tree](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/)

I just tried the deletion code in above link and it worked nice.

Answer (score 0):

There're 3 parts in deletion of a node from the binary search tree:

1. Find a node to delete.
2. Delete a node (free memory, etc).
3. Merge children of the deleted node.

In your particular code example, I'd say that looking for the node should be the responsibility of `void delete_node_helper(string s);`, deleting a node should be the responsibility of `void delete_node(Node *cur, string s);`, and merging the children should be the responsibility of the newly created function.

Given that the algorithms of the first two parts are pretty straighforward, let me explain in detail only the third one.

To merge two `BST`s (of which we know which one is left and which one is right) we should decide who will be whose child and perform the recursive merging if necessary. The code looks like this:

```
Node* merge(Node* left, Node* right) {
    if (left == nullptr) {
        return right;
    }
    if (right == nullptr) {
        return left;
    }
    if (rand() & 1) {                              // <- chose parent
        left->right = merge(left->right, right);
        return left;
    }
    right->left = merge(left, right->left);
    return right;
}
```

On the marked line we actually make a decision on which node will be whose parent. In this particular example, the result is random, but any other strategy may be implemented. For example, you could store heights (or sizes) in all nodes of your tree and make the smaller tree root child of a larger tree root.

Comment: Please comment if there's anything unclear in parts 1 and 2.

Comment: Please don't suggest using `rand()` in something like this. If anything, it hurts performance, because it has to do a function call and a conditional branch, without any real gain. Your remark about using subtree height is much better!

Comment: @G.Sliepen What would you recommend using instead of `rand()` in case we cannot modify the tree structure (which means, it does not store height or size or anything)? I personally don't know any better solutions

Comment: Just unconditionally choose one side (like left) as the parent. You must have a very weird tree and order of deletion for this to be much worse than choosing a random parent.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Disagree. Such example is very easy to construct and I can imagine it happening in the real-world problem, not saying about olympiad programming task or interview question. Given that we have recusrion here, replacing `rand()` with something else will give just a small non-asymptotic boost in performance while using always left (or right) branch will lead to `O(N)` asymptotics instead of `O(logN)` on a bad case. It doesn't worth it.